# Firebase error: TOO_MANY_TRIGGERS

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

In our Firebase application there is a list with lots of items in Realtime Database. Every create, update and delete operation on single item is processed by Firebase Cloud Function with onWrite trigger (in simplest case this function just counts items). But sometimes there is a need for bulk operation on items without need for individual processing. Let's say we want in single transaction remove all items and reset counters.

Earlier it worked just fine. Due to the limit of 1000 for number of Cloud Functions triggered by a single write (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits), no functions where triggered at all and it was desired outcome.

Now, without any change to application code we have an error

> Error: TOO_MANY_TRIGGERS: This request would cause too many functions to be triggered.

Same error appears in client application, Admin API and even when importing json using the web interface. Only option that works for us is processing of items in batches. But it is not transactional and takes up to tens of minutes instead of milliseconds as before.

What options do we have to bypass this error? Optimally this would be some switch to skip function triggering in case of exceeding the limit.

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem. Unfortunately, Firebase has its limits.

Comment: I managed to delete the data of more than 1000 records in multiple batches in which each batch is deleting 500 records only.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For anybody reading this question post-2018, there is now an option to disable strict enforcement for trigger limits.

Strict validation is enabled by default for write operations that trigger events. Any write operations that trigger more than 1000 Cloud Functions or a single event greater than 1 MB in size will fail and return an error reporting the limit that was hit. This might mean that some Cloud Functions aren't triggered at all if they fail the pre-validation.

If you're performing a larger write operation (for example, deleting your entire database), you might want to disable this validation, as the errors themselves might block the operation.

To turn off strictTriggerValidation, follow these steps:

- Get your Database secret from the Service accounts tab of your Project settings in the Firebase console.
- Run the following CURL request from your command line:

  > curl -X PUT -d "false" https://NAMESPACE.firebaseio.com/.settings/strictTriggerValidation/.json?auth\=SECRET

See here for the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits

Comment: Thats pretty useful, thanks. Should be set as the right answer.

Answer (score 6):

There is currently no way to prevent triggers from running in special circumstances.  The only way around this is to undeploy all your triggers, perform your updates, then deploy all your triggers again.

I would encourage you to [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) for this.

Comment: Unfortunately, undeploying and deploying triggers will not work well for our case because new data might be left unprocessed during this process.

Comment: I understand.  That's currently your only option.

Comment: @DougStevenson Why is deleting a single node with child nodes more than 1000 considered multiple triggers? We are deleting just one node, shouldn't that be just one trigger?

Comment: Too many triggers can be also invoked if you have a Cloud Function with a trigger for a .write operation. If you use only .update (for example when importing new data) this might be a workaround. But I agree, tricky

Answer (score 1):

I just got this error message in an older, Flutter project that I hadn't touched in quite some time.

> [firebase_database/unknown] TOO_MANY_TRIGGERS: This request would cause too many functions to be
> triggered.

It turned out that here it was caused by the fact that my Cloud Functions were still set to use Node v8, which was retired in early 2021.

Upgrading the Cloud Functions to use Node v12 (no other changes needed) removed the error message for me.

Answer (score 1):

Turning off strictTriggerValidation is solved my issue.

if you are using firebase tool you can follow these steps.

**Turn off strictTriggerValidation for entire project:**

> MAC

```
sudo firebase database:settings:set strictTriggerValidation false --project *my_project_id*
```

**If you need to turn off for particular instance:**

> MAC

```
sudo firebase database:settings:set strictTriggerValidation false --project *my_project_id* --instance *my_instance_name*
```

> check instances

```
sudo firebase database:instances:list --project *my_project_id*
```

Note: windows user please try without sudo

---

FYR:

Limitations: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits

Firebase CLI Commands: https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebase-tools/